# Matplotlib Basemap Resolution with PyQt makes Python Quit Unexpectedly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having difficulties using Matplotlibs Basemap in combination with a PyQt4 interface. Basically I create a Pyqt4 Canvas in which I plot a Matplotlib Basemap and some markers. I call the function in

```
self.button3 = QtGui.QPushButton('plot', self) 
self.button3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.plot(geom0))
```

And pass a geometry to my plot(geom0) function.

```
def plot(self, geom0):
                x1, y1 = zip(*((geom0.GetX(i), geom0.GetY(i)) for i in range(geom0.GetPointCount())))
                print geom0

                self.m = Basemap(projection='merc', resolution = None, area_thresh = 0.1,llcrnrlon=6.66321, llcrnrlat=50.48198, urcrnrlon=7.54761, urcrnrlat=51.46085)
                self.m.drawlsmask(land_color='lightgreen',ocean_color='aqua',lakes=True)

                x,y = self.m(x1, y1)
                self.m.plot(x, y, 'D-', markersize=4, linewidth=2, color='k', markerfacecolor='b')

                self.canvas.draw()
```

This works fine and the canvas is filled and a map without any kind of resolution is shown with my Linestring from `geom0` but when I change the resolution to low `'l'` or high `'h'` Python quits unexpectedly. Changing the resolution to low or high takes a while to calculate and I guess that is where the problem lies.

Do you have any ideas how I can tell PyQt to wait until the Basemap is calculated?

Answer (score -1):

Do not use lambda function for triggering.

Read this: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/25/passing-extra-arguments-to-pyqt-slot/

Comment: In the article you link, the author says to use lambda....